# Has network theory been successfully applied to protein expression within a cell?

Tags: evolution, protein-expression, network, biological-networks

I saw the following passage in the NPR [13.7 Cosmos & Culture](https://www.npr.org/sections/13.7/) commentary post [The Big Idea Behind Big Data](https://www.npr.org/sections/13.7/2017/11/17/564671867/the-big-idea-behind-big-data).

> Using the Internet's first generation of Big Data, researchers like physicist [Albert-László Barabási](http://barabasi.com/about/about) of Northeastern discovered hubs controlling the behavior of all large networks from protein regulation to webpages.
>
> "Nature evolved the metabolic network for cells over 4 billion years," says Barabasi, "but that same architecture emerged in the World Wide Web after just a decade."
>
> Different networks, same laws.

In a complex multicellular organism there is plenty of signaling between cells types and organs, and this can be viewed as a network.

But does [network theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_theory) also apply to protein regulation within a cell? I should really ask; *Has network theory been successfully applied to protein expression within a cell?*

I ask this because it seems according to this [clickable timeline template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Life_timeline) that 4 billion years ago, life was single-celled.

**edit:** There is a single link in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_theory) that points to [this paper](http://genome.cshlp.org/content/21/12/2067), but the abstract is over my head, and I'm not sure if this is a one-off attempt, or if network theory is an established method that has useful success in explaining/understanding/predicting protein expression within cells.

Comment: Yes, the tools of network theory can be used to analyze protein regulation, etc., within a cell. Lots of work on this, so this isn't an answer, just a pointer in one direction. One approach is to look at protein-protein interactions, etc, and see whether certain "motifs" in the network are more likely to occur in biology than randomly. An intro to some related ideas: Uri Alon, Nature Reviews Genetics 2007: http://www.weizmann.ac.il/mcb/UriAlon/sites/mcb.UriAlon/files/network_motifs_nature_genetics_review.pdf

Comment: @AJK OK that review is a great start! I'll give it a read, thanks.

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/92318/where-are-there-analyzable-signed-directed-network-datasets